# Observable not subscribing when using pipe in Rxjs - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

The following code **doesn't** subscribe:

```
this.store
      .select(petSelectors.selectPetData)
      .pipe(find(x => x.petName === petName)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

But if I do this, it **does** subscribe:

```
this.store.select(petSelectors.selectPetData).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**UPDATE: this works too**

```
const x = this.store .select(petSelectors.selectPetData).pipe(find(x => x));
```

but when I add the logic, it doesn't

I'm following the RxJS official documentation:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/find

I have even to tried inside the `pipe(), try with take(1), map(), etc` and when I do the `.subcribe()`, nothing gets printed. I have tried using the `async` pipe as well.

**Object:**

```
{
  "petName": "devpato"
}
```

**The pet name I'm passing is to compare the object with is 'devpato'**

Comment: how's your petSelectors.selectPetData observables looks like? can u give some details about your source observable

Comment: So if you use `.pipe(map(x => x))`, you dont get the same result as without the `pipe`?

Comment: @Code-EZ I'm using NgRx to store the state of the pets. Then using a selector to retrive the data that is already an Observable handled by Ngrx

Comment: @ConnorsFan to the rescue!! That actually worked. Idk what I was doing wrong when I was using the ```.map()``` but the ```.find() ``` still not working if i put the logic. this worked  ```const x = this.store
      .select(petSelectors.selectPetData).pipe(find(x => x));```

Comment: Can you test `.pipe(tap(x => console.log(x)).subscribe()` ?

Comment: Found my issue! @ConnorsFan basically ```x => x.petName === petName)``` doesn't work because x is the entire array, not a single object inside of the array. So i need to somehow iterate through ``x ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my issue! @ConnorsFan basically `x => x.petName === petName` doesn't work because `x` is the entire **array**, not a **single** object inside of the array. So i need to interate throught x

```
.pipe(map(x => x.find(u => u.petName ===petName));
```